# How to load a template file if new file is starting?

Tags: filetype

I'm a hobbyist *go* programmer, and I'm using `vim-go` to make vim efficient go editor.

One thing I like about vim-go is, whenever in a directory, when you open a new `.go` file. It adds this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("vim-go")
}
```

Note that it has the main function. And now if you create other .go files now on, you'll get this:

```
package main
```

---

I really like this feature. And would like to implement this for other filetypes. E.g. for Python files, I would like to do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

And for bash files, I would like to do this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

And so on.

What is the minimal setup that I need to do for each filetype *(Say I already have a template file for each)*?